# JSON.stringify then send as command line parameter

Tags: javascript, php, json, node.js, child-process

I am trying to make a NodeJS server, which, using child_process, stringifies an object, and sends it to a php file for processing, then waits for a result. My problem is that I can't figure out how to send my data to the php script for processing, because when it arrives to the script, the data is not a json_decode-able string anymore. Here's my NodeJs code:

```
dataString=JSON.stringify(data.user);
child_process.exec('php '+global.defaultPath+'php_functions\\authenticate.php ' + dataString, function (err, stdout, stderr){
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
    stdout=JSON.parse(stdout);
    if (stdout.status==1) global.connections[connection.suid].uid=stdout.uid;
});
```

And here is the authenticate.php file's beginning:

```
if (empty($argv[1])) {
echo "No user to authenticate...";
exit;
}

$user=json_decode($argv[1]);
```

The json_decode function in the php file, always returns null, and the error code is 4(BAD SYNTAX). If I log dataString in the server script, it returns:

```
{"uid":"1","accounthash":"4971b021ad2824fd42848e06bdce4d2b","suid":"xgv7-1"}
```

but when it arrives to the php script, the " marks are missing:

```
{uid:1,accounthash:4971b021ad2824fd42848e06bdce4d2b,suid:xgv7-1}
```

How could I send a javascript object to a PHP script?

Comment: have tried escaping your quotes `\"`?

Comment: I am guessing that the doublequotes are being removed by the shell preprocessor. Can you try and wrap `dataString` in single quotes?

Comment: @RiggsFolly same result...

Comment: @WhiteHat trying it right now

Answer (score 0):

1. Try to escape quotes.
2. Send JSON object as a string within "{}"

EX:

```
php -f authenticate.php "{\"uid\":\"1\",\"accounthash\":\"4971b021ad2824fd42848e06bdce4d2b\",\"suid\":\"xgv7-1\"}"
```